# CentOS 5: My Postgresql server version is different with my psql client. What should I do?

Tags: centos, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL 9.1 in CentOS 5 x86_64 VPS, with these following commands:

I specified which Postgresql version I'd like to install, so I choose 9.1 because I want to equate between development and production environment:

```
wget http://yum.pgrpms.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-5-x86_64/pgdg-centos91-9.1-4.noarch.rpm
```

and then

```
yum install postgresql91-server
```

Finally

```
service postgresql-9.1 initdb
chkconfig postgresql-9.1 on
service postgresql-9.1 start
```

After I finished all that and create my database, I run `psql myfirstdb` and I got this warning:

```
Welcome to psql 8.1.23 (server 9.1.11), the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
       \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help with psql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

WARNING:  You are connected to a server with major version 9.1,
but your psql client is major version 8.1.  Some backslash commands,
such as \d, might not work properly.
```

So, that said that I have 9.1 server and using psql client 8.1, and some commands like `\d` is not working.

How do I fix them?

Comment: Install the correct version of psql. Is that a problem? On debian `psql` is in a package called postgresql-client. Please list in your question all the postgresql related packages you have installed.

Answer (score 5):

It is likely you have more than one version of PostgreSQL and the wrong version of psql is being used. Try

```
sudo find / -name psql
```

Then check the version of the files and use  the right one by setting PATH.

```
 /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.2
```

You can also try

```
yum list installed | grep postgres
```

to see which versions of PostgreSQL are there in your system.

Comment: Correct. In my case, it is located at `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin`. I should use `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql` instead of `psql` because `psql` in `/usr/bin` is refer to a different version.

Comment: In my case, CentOS had `postgresql-libs.x86_64` in default version, which was 9.6, while I had 12 somewhere else and /usr/bin/psql pointed to 9.6. Listing installed as suggested here and removing libs solved the apparent mismatch

Answer (score 1):

The psql client is in a separate package from the psql server. It's commonly called postgresql-client.

Answer (score 1):

The client package, `postgresql91`, is depended on by the server package `postgresql91-server`. So you have the client installed, but it's not the default.

The RH packages use the alternatives mechanism, borrowed from Debian, to control which program gets run. You can pick the version to use with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config pgsql-psql
```

... though I'm not sure that's the case for the older version you're using.

Alternately, you can set your `PATH` up to put the newer binaries first. Append to `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin:$PATH
```

and then close and re-open the terminal.

Comment: I think it should be: sudo update-alternatives --config pgsql-psql